# providing access to Domino REST API

Tags: ibm-domino, lotus-notes

I created a user in Domino server as a Manager and also enabled Domino Data Access. But when I tried to call the `http://{host}/{database}/api/calendar/events` from the web browser, I could not be authenticated. Whereas, the Full administrator user was able to successfully call the api which means the endpoint has no issue. Is there some setting I need to enable for this user to be able to login and view the json response?

Comment: Try using the same user to open the database at the UI level instead of with the rest API. What happens?

Comment: @rhsatrhs, user still cannot authenticate at UI level

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with that user's permissions. It's either an ACL problem or a server-level access problem. Use the "Effective Access" button in the ACL, select that user name from the directory, and find out what the user's access to the database *really* is. If you are correct and the user does have Manager access, then check your server's configuration and make sure that the user is on the Access Server list and not on the Not Access Server list. See [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSKTMJ_8.5.3/com.ibm.help.domino.admin85.doc/H_SERVER_ACCESS_FOR_NOTES_USERS_INTERNET_USERS_AND_DOMINO_SERVERS_3202.html) and [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSKTMJ_9.0.1/admin/othr_serverdocumentsecuritytab_r.html).